# Keras auto generate batch sizes

Tags: keras

Is there a way to auto-generate the batch size based on the GPU's memory in keras? As far as I know, the batch size is mainly used to tweak how large the model uses up the vram. Currently, I just use trial and error to set a good batch size but I don't know if there is an easier way. This works okay, but it is a little tedious. If I am trying to run multiple different models where I can leave my computer running for multiple days, I'd like it to be most efficient with every model.

Edit:
Some pseudo code

```
# What I currently do
batch = 32
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch)
# here I have to manually change batch to maximize my gpu

# What I would prefer to do
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size='auto')
# where the auto takes into account the size of my gpu 
# and adjusts the batch_size automatically
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution?

Comment: pfff, nope. Just trial and error for now